# Android: Fail to store new values into Arraylists

Tags: android, static, arraylist, return

Im trying to do a XML File Explorer for Android devices and depending on what file the user selects, that file is opened and read. However I have a problem when I parse the XMLs and I send these values to the class where these values are showed. I have some Lists for the parsed values but the values only are stored for the first read file. If I select another files, in the window it shows always the same values ( the ones read for the first time). I think there is a problem because I use static for transferring these values between 2 classes and new values are never stored. If this is the problem what could be the solution in order to pass values into these 2 classes? Thank you
Here is the code where I parse the different files and store these values into lists.

```
public class XMLPullParserHandler {
    static List<Puntuacion> puntuaciones;
    private static Puntuacion puntuacion;
    static List<String> nombres = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> e = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> sr = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> pc = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> ps = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> ir = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> ip = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> por = new ArrayList<String>();



    private static String text;

    public XMLPullParserHandler() {
        puntuaciones = new ArrayList<Puntuacion>();
    }

    public static List<Puntuacion> getPuntuacion() {
        return puntuaciones;
    }

    public List<Puntuacion> parse(InputStream is) {

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
        XmlPullParser parser = null;
        try {
            factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            parser = factory.newPullParser();

            parser.setInput(is, null);

            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String tagname = parser.getName();
                switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("TEST")) {
                        // create a new instance of puntuacion



                        puntuacion = new Puntuacion();
                    }
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    text = parser.getText();
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("TEST")) {

                        puntuaciones.add(puntuacion);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("Nom_Test")) {
                        puntuacion.setValor((text));
                        nombres.add(text);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("NUMERO_ACIERTOS")) {
                        puntuacion.setValor_Transformado((text));

                        a.add(text);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("NUMERO_ERRORES")) {
                        puntuacion.setValor_PS((text));
                        e.add(text);


                } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("VALOR_PC")) {
                    puntuacion.setValor_PS((text));
                    pc.add(text);


                } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("VALOR_PS")) {
                    puntuacion.setValor_PS((text));
                    ps.add(text);


            } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("VALOR_IP")) {
                puntuacion.setValor_PS((text));
                ip.add(text);


        } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("VALOR_IR")) {
            puntuacion.setValor_PS((text));
            ir.add(text);

        }
        else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("VALOR_POR")) {
            puntuacion.setValor_PS((text));
            por.add(text);

        }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return puntuaciones;
    }

    public static String getNombre(int posicion){
        String[] ListN = new String[nombres.size()];
        ListN = nombres.toArray(ListN);
        return ListN[posicion];
    }
    public  static String getA(int posicion){
        String[] ListA = new String[a.size()];
        ListA = a.toArray(ListA);
        return ListA[posicion];
    }
    public  static String getE(int posicion){
        String[] ListE = new String[e.size()];
        ListE = e.toArray(ListE);
        return ListE[posicion];
    }
    public  static String getPC(int posicion){
        String[] ListPC = new String[pc.size()];
        ListPC = pc.toArray(ListPC);
        return ListPC[posicion];
    }
    public  static String getPS(int posicion){
        String[] ListPS = new String[ps.size()];
        ListPS = ps.toArray(ListPS);
        return ListPS[posicion];
    }
    public  static String getIP(int posicion){
        String[] ListIP = new String[ip.size()];
        ListIP = ip.toArray(ListIP);
        return ListIP[posicion];
    }
    public  static String getIR(int posicion){
        String[] ListIP = new String[ir.size()];
        ListIP = ir.toArray(ListIP);
        return ListIP[posicion];
    }
    public static String getP(int posicion){
        String[] ListIP = new String[por.size()];
        ListIP = por.toArray(ListIP);
        return ListIP[posicion];
    }

}
```

The way I retrieve the Arraylists into the other class is like in the following examples:

```
PS1.setText(XMLPullParserHandler.getPS(0));
IR1.setText(XMLPullParserHandler.getIR(0));
```

Thank you for your time

EDIT: Here is the code where the new instance of  XMLPullParserHandler is generated in the XMLPullParserActivity:

```
    public class XMLPullParserActivity {


        public static  void Parse(Context context){




            List<Puntuacion> puntuacion = null;
            try {
                XMLPullParserHandler parser = new XMLPullParserHandler();
                puntuacion = parser.parse(context.getAssets().open(MainActivity.fileName()));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }




    }
```

MainActivity when I call to Parse() method:

```
file = new File(path.get(position));
                file.getName();
                XMLPullParserHandler parser = new XMLPullParserHandler();

                XMLPullParserActivity.Parse(this);
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Correccion.class);
                     startActivity(i);





}
```

Comment: Please try to improve variable naming. two letter variable names are considered cryptic and you might mess up `ir` with `ip` without realising...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the problem lays in using `static` fields. You are initializing your `ArrayLists` only once, when the `XMLPullParserHandler` class is loaded. After that you're just calling `add()` on these lists. So when you're parsing new files you're just adding values to those of previous files. I suggest you to redesign your application a bit:

- Rework your `XMLPullParserHandler` to parse a file and return you a `List` of custom items. It shouldn't store any information, just parse and return
- Create a new instance of `XMLPullParserHandler` every time you need a file parsed, call its `parse()` method, which returns you a list of items, and then display these items

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Egor, however Im a bit lost. I editted something and I create a new instance of XML when I open the selected file:  XMLPullParserActivity.Parse(this);
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Correccion.class);
                     startActivity(i);

Comment: @Katherine99, You don't really need the XMLPullParserActivity, all the more so it's not even an Activity. Create an instance of XMLPullParserHandler inside the MainActivity and call its parse() method right there.

Comment: Sorry Egor but I dont know very well how to do it, You mean to write this into the mainActivity: XMLPullParserHandler Parser = new XMLPullParserHandler();
Parser.parse();???   Thank you again

Comment: @Katherine99, Yes, you're right. By the way, it's uncommon to name variables starting with an uppercase letter in Java, you should use lowercase letters only.